# sqlite3 python unexpected termination

Tags: python, sqlite

I have set a sqlite3 database. I filled it with some data(~4million records ~1.2Gb of data).
Then I do some queries (selects/deletes/updates).
The problem is that sometimes after the insertions the script stops without an error. Sometimes it runs normal until the end.
These are the type of queries I run:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sqlite3
import csv
import os
import glob
import sys
import time

db = 'test.db'

conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
conn.text_factory = str  # allows utf-8 data to be stored

c = conn.cursor()
i = 0
### traverse the directory and process each .csv file

##print("debug")
csvfile =('/home/Desktop/Untitled Folder/Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv')
with open(csvfile, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    t = time.time()
    header = True
    for row in reader:
        if header:
            # gather column names from the first row of the csv
            header = False

            sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table"
            c.execute(sql)
            #print("debug 1")
            sql = "CREATE TABLE test_table (ID INTEGER,FBI_Code INTEGER,Updated_On TEXT,District TEXT,Beat INTEGER,Primary_Type TEXT,Location BLOB,Latitude REAL,Arrest INTEGER,Domestic INTEGER,Longitude REAL,Community_Area INTEGER,Case_Number INTEGER,Block TEXT,Location_Description TEXT,Ward INTEGER,IUCR INTEGER,Year INTEGER, Date TEXT,Y_Coordinate INTEGER,Description TEXT,X_Coordinate INTEGER);"
            c.execute(sql)
            #print("debug 2")
            insertsql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" 
            rowlen = len(row)
            #print("debug 3")
        else:
            # skip lines that don't have the right number of columns
            #print("debug 4")
            #if len(row) == rowlen:
                #print("debug 5")
            try:
                c.execute(insertsql, row)
            except:
                print("problem in row %d" % i)
                print(row)
                continue

            #    print("debug 6")
            i +=1
            if i == 1000:
                conn.commit()
####            if i == 4000000:
####                break
##            #print (row)
conn.commit()

print('\nTime for Insertions TOTAL~> \n')
print(float( time.time() -t ))

print('\nTime for Insertions per Query~> \n')
print(float( time.time() -t )/i) 
del rows
rows = list()

print('\nTime for Selections ~> Domestic\n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Domestic == 'false'")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows
rows = list()

print('\nTime for Selections ~> Arrests\n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Arrest == 'false'")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows
rows = list()

print('\nTime for Selections ID~> \n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE ID < 9938614")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows
rows = list()

print('\nTime for Selections ~> Primary_Type\n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Primary_Type == 'BATTERY'")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows
rows = list()

print('\nTime for Selections Year~> \n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Year <= 2014")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows
rows = []

print('\nTime for Updates ~> YEAR\n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("UPDATE test_table SET Year = '2016' WHERE Year == '2014'")
print(float( time.time() -t ))

print('\nTime for Selections Year~> \n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE Year <= 2014")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))

print('\nTime for DELETIONS ~> Domestic\n')
t = time.time()
c.execute("DELETE FROM test_table WHERE Domestic == 'false'")
rows = c.fetchall()
print(float( time.time() -t ))
print(len(rows))
del rows

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Every time I reassign the *row list* because after some queries I run out of memory. But I do not think that's the problem(just in case I used del rows & reassigned it, it was slower that way). Anyway after some of these queries the script stops without an error and I can not figure out why because there are some times in which it runs OK.

**Edit**

I have included the code above. The problem is that after the insertion part when I do the queries the script is terminated without any error.

For example it goes till here:

> ...
>   Time for Selections ~> Arrests
>
> 123.231
>
> 3928182

and then it terminates. In the 1st approach I did not delete the list and Cython produced core dump errors when I tried to re-declare the list. Now that I delete and then declare the list Cython runs ok. My question is why does not python catch any exceptions?

After the reassignment of the list, garbage collector clears the trash data (and it does, as I saw from linux monitor) but it crashes without errors. And the most annoying is that sometimes it runs ok till the end.

Comment: If it exits unexpectedly without an error (or gets stuck), you could add `print` statements to see how far it goes until it stops.

Comment: every query before it's executed has a print statement so i know in which query i am. But when it stops/crashes it is not at the same query as the crash before.

Comment: I also have tried to reassign the row list as , row = list() but still it crashes exits without an error. Sometimes is at the first 2-3 queries and sometimes at the end of the queries.

Comment: Depending on the OS you use, it could as well be the OOM killer. `c.fetchall()` is not the best way to retrieve the data, as for a short time the data are in the memory twice (at the DB library and in Python). A better way would be to iterate over the cursor and/or use a ServerSide cursor.

Comment: I converted the script to Cython and it seems that the error is at the reassigning of the list. Strange, python doesn't catch any exceptions.

Comment: That code does not do anything with `rows`. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is calling `fetchall()`. Why aren't you iterating though the cursor?

Comment: fetchall() is ok. i handled the bug by creating for each query a function without deleting anything just letting gc do the dirty work after each function finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, my solution was to create a new  cursor, then I handled the SQL Select with one cursor and inserts/deletes with the other one.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn.cursor()
```